# Can the Flex Builder Profiler be used with an AIR application?

Tags: air, flexbuilder, profiler

I am trying to profile my AIR app in Flex Builder.
The app is starting but not the profiler.
Is it actually possible to profile AIR apps in FlexBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
You may need to switch to the profiler view via the link in the top right of Builder.

Comment: I looked in the Profiler perspective but nothing happens